# how to select only the int values in a column that is nvarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CAST and IsNumeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338075/cast-and-isnumeric)

I have a database column that is nvarchar, but i want to only get the rows of the database that have integers in that column field is it possible?

Comment: Explain "have integers" - if the value is "A1", should you get the row?  Or are you looking for rows where the column value is entirely integers?

Comment: The row has to be completely integers, what happened was i imported an excel sheet and the column that i need to use to join two tables must be an int.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Adding the '.0e0' to the end of the column in the ISNUMERIC check will ensure that only integers will be found.

```
SELECT *
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE ISNUMERIC(YourColumn + '.0e0') = 1
```

Comment: +1 Don't forget that ISNUMERIC('' + '.0e0') = 1

Comment: suggested revision taking Alex's suggestion into consideration - evaluate both the column and the `column + '.0e0'` which should cover both cases.

Comment: `SELECT ISNUMERIC('-' + '.0e0')` and `ISNUMERIC('+' + '.0e0')` return 1 also (as well as all the white space characters)

Comment: `isnumeric` doesn't guarantee that an int will fit the number. it could be a bigint or a larger numeric. Example: 3,000,000,000 won't fit an int, and precision 20 numbers won't fit a bigint.

Comment: A more complex check is:
`SELECT * FROM YourTable
    WHERE CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(LTRIM(RTRIM(YourColumn)) + '.0e0') = 1 
               THEN CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(YourColumn))!='+'
                          AND LTRIM(RTRIM(YourColumn))!=''
                          AND ABS(CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(YourColumn)) AS DECIMAL(25,0)))<=2147483647
                         THEN 1
                         ELSE 0
                         END
                ELSE 0
                END = 1`

Answer (score 0):

You check for isnumeric:

```
select evalcolumn from table where isnumeric(evalcolumn) = 1
```

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` has a lot of caveats - Joe's answer is better since it checks for `INT` and not just for a number.  Your method will allow values like `1e2` as numeric.

Comment: `select isnumeric('3d8')` = 1

Comment: That's true. One more lesson learned!