# SQL: How use case and cast in a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, casting, case

I want to cast VARCHAR to INT, but in my table i have some value like '???' then SQL Server launch this expcetion :

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '????' to data type int.
Severity 16
```

I could convert this '???' to NULL, that's no problem, but how do that ?

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO labbd11..movie(title, year)
SELECT movies.title, 
       CASE movies.mvyear IS '????' THEN NULL ELSE CAST (movies.mvyear AS INT)
FROM disciplinabd..movies
```

But nothing works ..

Any ideas guys ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might just want to solve this in general and deal with any non-int value the same way

```
 INSERT INTO labbd11..movie(title, year) 
    SELECT movies.title, 
           CASE WHEN IsNumeric(movies.mvyear+ '.0e0') <> 1  THEN NULL 
                ELSE CAST (movies.mvyear AS INT) END  
      FROM disciplinabd..movies
```

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338075/cast-and-isnumeric)

Comment: @Thanks so much for you help guys, you guys rock!

Answer (score 5):

I believe you would want something like

```
INSERT INTO labbd11..movie(title, year) 
  SELECT movies.title, 
         CAST( CASE movies.mvyear 
                    WHEN '????' THEN NULL 
                    ELSE movies.mvyear
                 END AS INT) 
    FROM disciplinabd..movies
```

You want your CASE statement to return a VARCHAR (either the `MVYEAR` or NULL) and then you want the CAST to operate on the result of the CASE.

Answer (score 0):

```
    INSERT INTO labbd11..movie(title, year) 
    SELECT movies.title, 
           CASE WHEN movies.mvyear = '????' THEN NULL 
                ELSE CAST (movies.mvyear AS INT) END  
      FROM disciplinabd..movies
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO labbd11..movie(title, year)
    SELECT
        movies.title,
        CAST(CASE WHEN movies.mvyear = '????' THEN NULL ELSE movies.mvyear END AS INT)
    FROM
        disciplinabd..movies
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
CAST(NULLIF(movies.mvyear,'????') AS INT)
```