# Using IF IsNumeric as Argument

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

i was wondering how to use IsNumeric in SQL, it's a bit different from VBScript, but i think i was able to get around it, ie:

```
 IF 1 = ISNUMERIC('5675754674') 
 BEGIN 
 ...
 END
```

Would this be a way around it?  What I really want to do is:

```
IF ISNUMERIC('5675754674')
BEGIN 
... 
END
```

but that gives an error.  Example 1 seems to work, but just making sure i'm doing this right, wasn't able to find any good resources online about it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no `boolean` in SQL Server. This means you can't just say `IF (expression)`; you must compare it to something, because it does return `true` or `false` in the same sense as you're probably used to in other languages.

Just a preference, but I would prefer to write it this way:

```
IF ISNUMERIC('5675754674') = 1
BEGIN
...
END
```

There is no way in SQL Server to avoid the comparison to 1, as in your second example.

Also as an aside you should be aware of the weaknesses of `ISNUMERIC()` - it can give false positives for "numeric" values such as `.`, `CHAR(9)`, `e`, `$` and a host of other non-numeric strings. If you want to know if something is an integer, for example, better to say:

```
IF '5675754674' NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
BEGIN
...
END
```

But even that is not a complete and valid test because it will return true for values `> (2^32)-1` and it will return false for negative values.

Another downside to `ISNUMERIC()` is that it will return true if the value can be converted to *any* of the numeric types, which is not the same as *all* numeric types. Often people test for `ISNUMERIC()` and then try to cast a `FLOAT` to a `SMALLINT` and the conversion fails.

In SQL Server 2012 you will have a new method called [`TRY_CONVERT()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) which returns `NULL` if the conversion to the specified data type is not valid.

Answer (score 5):

You are right, ISNUMERIC() returns an int.
You can check the documentation: [ISNUMERIC()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The `IF` statement in SQL requires a boolean expression after the `IF` - see [the MSDN reference here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms182717%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

SQL isn't the best at handling casting between types without using something like `CAST()` or `CONVERT()`, which means that the `int` value `ISUNUMERIC()` returns will only be resolved as a boolean when you use some comparator (=,<,>,etc) to produce a true/false result.

`IF ISNUMERIC('5675754674') = 1` is probably the best way to write this out in TSQL - it clearly describes the intent of 'If this value run through this function returns 1 (can be evaluated as a numeric data type),  then do this thing.'

With that in mind, you should be aware that `ISNUMERIC` only checks that the value you pass in will evaluate to -any- available numeric data type. This can lead to trouble if the data you're running through contains scientific notation or other irregularities; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338075/cast-and-isnumeric) for more information.