# SQL Server - Using Sum of Count

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am using SQL Server. The Formula I need to use is (Good-Bad)/Total_Responses. A Good is when the value is >=9 and a Bad is <=6.

The Data I have is:

```
DATE        Q1  Q2
2012-03-04   9   9
2012-03-04   8   8
2012-03-04   7   9
2012-03-04   4  NA
2012-03-04  10  10
2012-03-04   8   3
2012-03-04   3   4
2012-03-04   2   6
2012-03-04   6   8
2012-03-04  NA   6
```

I know I am going to have to use a "CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Q1)=1" to make sure it does not use the NA values (They are stored as Nvarchar)

So the formula would end up being (5-8)/18=-0.16666
So overall I am trying to get the data to look like:

```
DATE        Promotor_Score
2012-03-04        -0.16666
```

Thank You!

Comment: Why NVARCHAR? Do you expect to store umlauts, pound symbols and Hebrew?

Comment: Be careful of `ISNUMERIC`... it does not always do what you think it should.

Comment: To illustrate the point made by @JeremyHolovacs - I wrote this post in 2002, still relevant today: http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/what-is-wrong-with-isnumeric.html

Comment: @AaronBertrand Do you know off hand if `(IsNumeric(Q1 + '.0e0') = 1)` catches all the same values IsReallyNumeric catches? I've been using that [since I read the SO question Cast And IsNumeric](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338075/cast-and-isnumeric)

Comment: @Conrad All valid INTs, I would think so, but not 100% sure as I haven't tested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this do the trick?

```
SELECT  Date,
        CAST((SUM(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Q1) != 1 THEN 0
                 WHEN CAST(Q1 AS int) >= 9 THEN 1
                 WHEN CAST(Q1 AS int) <= 6 THEN -1
                 ELSE 0 END)
        + SUM(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Q2) != 1 THEN 0
                 WHEN CAST(Q2 AS int) >= 9 THEN 1
                 WHEN CAST(Q2 AS int) <= 6 THEN -1
                 ELSE 0 END)) AS float)
        / (SUM(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Q1) != 1 THEN 0
                   ELSE 1 END)
        + SUM(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Q2) != 1 THEN 0
                   ELSE 1 END))
FROM    Questions
GROUP BY Date
```

Or if 'NA' is the only non-numeric value, test for it explicitly.

Comment: I get this result: `2012-03-04 | 0` - you need to be careful about integer math. Did you try your code?

Comment: @Aaron - it's doing integer division, as you say. Fixed.

Comment: Look a bit closer. It's there. Line 9. Only numerator or denominator needs casting for force floating point division, as I'm sure you know.

Comment: Getting incorrect syntax near ). Highly recommend you get your code working before posting 15 updates. DOUBLE is not a valid data type in SQL Server.

Comment: @Aaron - where does 15 come from?

Comment: I was exaggerating a little. I meant that you changed the answer multiple times from one non-working version to another.

Comment: I prefer to think of it as iterating towards a working solution. ;) Fair comment.

Comment: HAH it would make sense that SO supports Agile!

Answer (score 0):

Buildin on @DavidM answer, I added float conversion and Q2 column awareness:

```
SELECT [date], 
1e0 -- a float multiplier to avoid integer value
* SUM( 0
    -- get the positive, negative or neutral from q1
    + CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(q1) != 1 THEN  0
    WHEN CAST(q1 AS int) >= 9    THEN  1
    WHEN CAST(q1 AS int) <= 6    THEN -1
    ELSE 0 END
    -- get the positive, negative or neutral from q2
    + CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(q2) != 1 THEN  0
    WHEN CAST(q2 AS int) >= 9    THEN  1
    WHEN CAST(q2 AS int) <= 6    THEN -1
    ELSE 0 END
)
/ SUM( 0
    -- get the number of valid questions from q1
    + CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(q1) != 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END        
    -- get the number of valid questions from q2
    + CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(q2) != 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
)
FROM Questions
GROUP BY Date;
```

Comment: Two quick comments (1) shouldn't your last ISNUMERIC check be against Q2? I think it currently only works because both columns have the same number of rows that either pass or fail the check (2) I think relying on ISNUMERIC is dangerous since any old garbage can be entered into that column. If the OP confirms that `'NA'` is the only possible non-numeric value, it is safer to check for that value explicitly than to rely on ISNUMERIC.

Comment: Sure @AaronBertrand: (1) was a mistype and it is corrected; (2) if only 'NA' values should be not considered, what to do with other (garbage) values? I don't recommend saving numeric data on `VARCHAR` at all, but that was part of the problem @Brad presented.