# SQL Syntax Error using IsNumeric on Varchar Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to execute a SQL-Statement

```
SELECT * 
FROM Menu
WHERE ISNumeric(Data) = 1
AND Data = 296
```

where the `Data` field may contain numeric or non-numeric contents.
But I am getting syntax error something like

> Syntax error on converting the varchar-value '/home' in a column of Data type int.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since `DATA` column is varchar, you need to enclosed the value (*296*) with single quote

```
SELECT * 
FROM   Menu
WHERE  ISNumeric(Data) = 1 AND Data = '296'
```

you can still directly query without using `ISNUMERIC` here, and increases performance since you don;t have to check every record for numeric values.

Using `IsNumeric` is pointless, *I guess*, in your situation.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   Menu
WHERE  Data = '296'
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, SQL doesn't [guarantee short circuit evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789231/is-the-sql-where-clause-short-circuit-evaluated), therefore the `IsNumeric(Data)` filter won't prevent evaluation of the second predicate, `Data = 296`, if the first condition is false.

What you can do however is leave the comparison as a char literal, e.g.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Menu
WHERE ISNumeric(Data) = 1
AND Data = '296';
```

Out of interest, why would you need to do the `IsNumeric` check if you are comparing to an exact numeric value?

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @StuartLC's answer, one workaround for this is by using a subquery to obtain all the numeric values first, e.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
    SELECT CAST(Data AS int) AS Data, 
           -- Other fields
    FROM   Menu
    WHERE  ISNumeric(Data) = 1
) subquery
WHERE subquery.Data = 296
```

Although note you will need to be sure you won't have decimal numbers, or scientific notation, or that sort of thing, as IsNumeric will return `1` for these. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338075/cast-and-isnumeric) will help you resolve issues around that...