# SQL Server 2008 R2 bug or what?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am observing a strange behaviour. The following code that is related to conversion of a substring of `nvarchar` to `tinyint` works fine:

```
DECLARE @s nvarchar(50) = N'Line 1'
DECLARE @n tinyint = SUBSTRING(@s, 6, 10)

SELECT
        N'Line 1' AS explicit_nvarchar,
        @s AS nvarchar_variable,
        SUBSTRING(@s, 6, 10) AS nvarchar_substring
        , @n AS tinyint_var_converted_earlier
        , CAST(SUBSTRING(@s, 6, 10) AS tinyint) AS cast_sub_var
        , CAST(SUBSTRING(N'Line 1', 6, 10) AS tinyint) AS cast_nvarchar_substr
```

I can observe the following output in the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio:

[image].

However, the code that tries to do with the `SELECT` from the tables fails if the commented line is uncommented:

```
Select 
    [order].[identifier] As [order_identifier],
    [plan_data].[starts_on] As [from],
    [plan_data].[ends_on] As [to],
    [workplace].[identifier] AS line_identifier,
    SUBSTRING([workplace].[identifier], 6, 10) AS line_no_str
    --, CAST(SUBSTRING([workplace].[identifier], 6, 10) AS int) AS line_no
From 
    ...
```

With commented line...
[image]

but with uncommented line (both for conversion to `tinyint` or `int`)...

[image]

**Update:** Strange. I have added the last line to the WHERE to check whether all lines
contain the `'Line...`

```
Where
    [plan].[identifier] = @lPlanIdentifier And
    (
        [plan_data].[starts_on] Between @fromUTC And @toUTC Or
        [plan_data].[ends_on] Between @fromUTC And @toUTC)
    AND LEFT([workplace].[identifier], 4) = N'Line'
```

... and all of a sudden it works also with the uncommented line. How can I discover what causes the problem?

**Update2:** I should have followed the [Hamlet Hakobyan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14468720/1346705) exactly as it was published. When looking inside the table, I can see:

[image]

Comment: Are there only 4 rows? Or are there any that have a line_identifier that won't parse?

Comment: Do you have a row in the table that has an `identifier` value of `undefined` by chance?  Can you show the entire contents of the table you are querying?

Comment: Updated. The SELECT part contains only the lines that I show. The result with the commented line returns 698 rows without any problem. The strings are all `Line 1`, `Line 2`, `Line 3`, or `Line 4` (at least I am not aware of any different value). After uncommenting, it fails immediately.

Comment: Short answer: no, this is not a bug. Similar problem [link](http://rusanu.com/2011/08/10/t-sql-functions-do-no-imply-a-certain-order-of-execution/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have value in `identifier` column for which `SUBSTRING([workplace].[identifier], 6, 10)` returns `ined`.

Try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM [workplace]
WHERE SUBSTRING([identifier], 6, 10) = N'ined'
```

Comment: Good idea. But then it returns no records with commented line and fails the same way with uncommented line. See the update part at the end of the question about another try -- all records contain `Line...`.

Comment: All records can contain `Line`. For instance `Line ined`. Are you tried run given query?

Comment: +2. You are right. It was `N'Undefined'` that would not be the part of the result, but at some stage, the substring was calculated.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by the comments and other answer(s), you have a value in `[workplace].[identifier]` for one or more rows that fails to cast to an `INT`.  When you added the following to the `WHERE` clause, you eliminated the row(s) that has this data before it was converted in the `SELECT` clause:

```
LEFT([workplace].[identifier], 4) = N'Line'
```

Run the following to get a distinct list of values in `[workplace].[identifier]`

```
SELECT DISTINCT [workplace].[identifier]
FROM [workplace]
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have an error converting a varchar to a number the easiest way to find the data is using `IsNumeric`. However `IsNumeric` doesn't mean `IsInteger` so its worth removing scientific or decimal formats as described by [G Mastros](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1408129/g-mastros) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/338122/119477)

```
SELECT
    [order].[identifier] As [order_identifier],
    [plan_data].[starts_on] As [from],
    [plan_data].[ends_on] As [to],
    [workplace].[identifier] AS line_identifier,
    SUBSTRING([workplace].[identifier], 6, 10) AS line_no_str
    --, CAST(SUBSTRING([workplace].[identifier], 6, 10) AS int) AS line_no
FROM
  ...

WHERE 

   IsNumeric(SUBSTRING([workplace].[identifier], 6, 10) + '.0e0') = 0
```

If you can't fix it but you can use a default value than you could use a case statement to do the conversion only when its legal to do so.

```
SELECT
    [order].[identifier] As [order_identifier],
    [plan_data].[starts_on] As [from],
    [plan_data].[ends_on] As [to],
    [workplace].[identifier] AS line_identifier,
    CASE WHEN IsNumeric(SUBSTRING([workplace].[identifier], 6, 10) + '.0e0') = 1
             THEN CAST(SUBSTRING([workplace].[identifier], 6, 10) AS int) 
             ELSE Null --Default to null in this example
    END as line_no
```