# Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 33 Error converting data type varchar to numeric

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, casting

```
declare @rent decimal
set @rent = 1000
--select format(@rent,'C0')
select case when ISNULL(CAST(@rent AS varchar(50)),'') = '' then @rent else cast(format(@rent,'C') as varchar(50)) end AS Rent
```

I am getting this error while using the `format` function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1 Error converting data type varchar to numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19018377/msg-8114-level-16-state-5-line-1-error-converting-data-type-varchar-to-numeri)

Comment: You cannot return decimal in when clause and varchar in else clause. It must be a single data type.

Comment: What is your database? And what is your requirement? What you wants to do with your input 1000?

Comment: What exactly is your question? The error itself is self-explanatory?

Comment: Getting the error in else block while using Format function, the casting i couldn't figure out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this following:

```
declare @rent decimal
set @rent = 1000
--select format(@rent,'C0')
select 
case 
    when ISNULL(CAST(@rent AS varchar(50)),'') = '' then NULL
    -- I have used NULL as if the value = '' then it should be 
    -- presented by Null which is allowed for all data type
    else cast(format(@rent,'C') as varchar(50)) 
end AS Rent
```

In fact you can directly use the formatting as below as if the input is `NULL`, it will automatically return `NULL`. No need to go through a `CASE` expression.

```
declare @rent decimal
--set @rent = 1000
--select format(@rent,'C0')
select cast(format(@rent,'C') as varchar(50)) AS Rent
```

Comment: I want to suppress the null output that's  why used case statement