# How can I fetch rows using numeric values as condition?

Tags: cakephp

A colum in my databse table has alphanumeric values. I want to get only the rows, having numeric values in this column.

```
$this->Mymodel->find('all', 
    'condition' => array('Mymodel.field') => ???)
);
```

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version, and when it's about queries don't forget the DBMS/Schema details. http://stackoverflow.com/q/5064977 | http://stackoverflow.com/q/338075 | http://stackoverflow.com/q/16195986 etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using MySQL, you could use [**Regular Expressions**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp).

```
$this->Mymodel->find('all', 'conditions' => array('Mymodel.field REGEXP "^[0-9]+$"'));
```