# How can determine and avoid records based on its left most String values are numeric in SQL Query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table `AgentDetail`, and I need to create a query which returns only records which contain left most 5 numeric digits.

The table has 3 columns

```
AgentId, AgentName, AgentTextCode
```

where in the `AgentTextCode` column, there could be 5 digits or any text value (sometime 2 bytes chars). So output records should be only those which have a value which starts with 5 numeric digits (decimal value not possible).

Sample data & output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `LIKE` here:

```
SELECT
    AgentID, AgentName, AgentTextCode
FROM yourTable
WHERE AgentTextCode LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%';
```

SQL Server's `LIKE` operator supports some primitive regex capabilities, as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IsNumeric and Substring from TSQL:

```
SELECT
    AgentID, AgentName, AgentTextCode
FROM yourTable
WHERE ISNUMERIC(Replace(Replace(substring(AgentTextCode, 1, 5),'+','A'),'-','A') + '.0e0') = 1;
GO
```

Reference here:
[CAST and IsNumeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338075/cast-and-isnumeric)

Comment: This won't work in every case.  For example, `ISNUMERIC('$12.123')` returns true, but the first characters are not all strictly numbers.

Comment: this will cater for +, -, $ signs